# Смена отображения контента в модальном окне SimpleModal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Использую для модального окна `SimpleModal` на jQuery.
Как сделать заголовок и подвал внутри модального окна фиксированными так, чтобы содержимое прокручивалось внутри них?

```html
<div id="simplemodal-container">
    <div>Вот тут бы заголовок</div>
    <div class="simplemodal-wrap">
        <div id="simplemodal-data">
            Ну а тут куча содержимого со скроллом
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>А вот тут подвал</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Может я не понимаю сути вопроса, но предлагаю такое решение.
Для класса simplemodal-wrap задаете нужную высоту и ставите overflow: auto;

```
.simplemodal-wrap {
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: вот в том то и дела, у simplemodal-wrap уже есть overflow: auto

Comment: Давайте полный код: css, html, jquery.